# Why does Perl think -1 is true?

Tags: perl, boolean

This is a piece of common example code:

```
while (1) { 
    print "foo\n"; 
}
```

which prints 'foo' forever.

```
perl foo.pl
foo
foo
foo
...
```

and

```
while (0) { print "foo\n"; }
```

dies quietly as you expect:

```
perl test.pl
```

Can someone explain why this is a useful implementation of while?  This works on 5.10 at least, Unix and MacOS X:

```
while (-1) { print "foo\n"; }
```

which gives

```
foo
foo
foo
...
```

Comment: `-1` is considered to be a true value in many languages.

Comment: In Perl, 0 is false; anything that isn't false is true.

Comment: I'm curious as to what led to this question. Is there a language that considers -1 false?

Comment: I looked at several example articles and none of them mention negative integers.  Seems like something they would have pointed out.

Comment: They did point it out. In toolic's answer there is a quote from perlsyn that clearly states that any non-zero value is considered "true". Question is, why did you think that negative integers were excluded?

Comment: Stop downvoting these kind of questions! Answers and explanations here may still be valuable to beginners.

Comment: Just by way of comparison, here's what K&R say in The C Programming Language (second edition, p. 223):  "In both forms of the `if` statement, is evaluated, including all side-effects, and *if it compares unequal to 0*, the first substatement is executed." (Emphisis added). So this is the standard way of doing things in any language.

Comment: @Leonardo To be fair, in its current form this *is* a poor question (sorry, OP!). It starts from an unfounded, unreasonable and unexplained false assumption and throws around several misconceptions without getting to the point. I agree that a related question (“what values are considered `true`, and why?”) is worth asking. The downvotes here, I assume, are because this is precisely *not* asked.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - I see what you mean. But false and poor assumptions will remain the same until they are asked about and answered by those who know better.

Comment: Just change the title of the question. Perl "thinks" its true because it is true.  If you had title the question "Why is -1 defined as true in Perl" you would have gotten what you were looking for faster

Comment: Duplicate an answer, that will work best here is to specify a [real perl true/false expression hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21135349/257319)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If anything, one could say `-1` is more likely to be true than `1` since `-1` (`111..111b`) is the bitwise negation of zero (`000..000b`). BASIC and GW-BASIC used -1 when they needed to return a true value.

Regardless, Perl decided that values that mean "empty" or "nothing" are false. Most languages take a similar view. Specifically, integer zero, floating point zero, the string zero, the empty string and undef are false.

This is [documented](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood), although the documentation is poorly worded. (It lists `()` as a value that's false, but there is no such value.)

Aside from consistency, it's very useful to take this approach. For example, it allows one to use

```
if (@x)
```

instead of

```
if (@x != 0)
```

Comment: In list context there is a value for the empty list, compare `if (($x) = (undef)) { #true` vs `if (($x) = ()) { #false`. In both cases `$x` is set to undef, but the truth of the expression is determined by the number of elements in the list, not by the values of those elements.

Comment: @Ven'Tatsu, No, there isn't. The code you posted tests the return value of the assignment, not the return value of `()`.

Comment: @Ven'Tatsu, In case you're curious, list assignment in scalar context returns the number of elements returned by the RHS. e.g. `say scalar( ($x)=(4,5) );` prints `2` and `say scalar( ($x)=() );` prints `0`.)

Answer (score 19):

Every non-zero integer evaluates to `true`. And 0 is always `false`

Comment: these answers are tautological.  i was not asking whether this is true, i can see that. the question is WHY this is true.  I looked at a few articles before i posted this and actually this fact is not mentioned that I can see.  positive integers are all the examples usually given.

Comment: 11 upvotes.. =) It's the really easy answers that gives the biggest reputation rewards.

Comment: @shigeta - That's an easy answer: it is what it is <i>by definition</i>. As for the reason it was decided this way, there are many explanations, but it was mostly for convenience (pseudocode: if val = 0 then <false> else <true>)

Comment: @shigeta "I looked at a few articles....and actually this fact is not mentioned that I can see."  This is a common beginner mistake: Looking for answers in the wrong place.  Read the Perl documentation that comes with Perl.  http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood

Comment: @shigeta - because Larry said so way back when.

Comment: None of this provides a serious answer to the question.

Comment: @reinierpost, the question is somewhat incoherent, or, at best, hopelessly ambiguous. Furthermore, I'd challenge the OP to find a single programming language out there where the final example in the question doesn't hold.

Comment: @reinierpost - this is a serious answer. Care to elaborate why do you think it is not?

Comment: It's serious, and relevant, but not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 16):

From [perldoc perlsyn (Truth and Falsehood)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood):

> The number 0, the strings '0'  and '' , the empty list () , and undef
>   are all false in a boolean context. All other values are true.

`-1` is considered true.

Comment: I have always considered that when testing a list in boolean context, I am really implicitly testing it in scalar context, which when empty gives zero, thus false. Is it really true that a list has a boolean context evaluation that doesn't get first the scalar treatment?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Joel: More likely, the empty list is just mentioned to avoid confusion. In scalar context, an empty array evaluates to `0` (the number of elements) and an empty list evaluates to `undef` (its final element), both of which are already false without requiring any special-case logic to handle it.

Comment: @reinierpost - The question states "why Perl thinks -1 is true", and this answer says "only a, b, and c are true, and everything else is false." *Entailment* makes this answer a perfect valid one.

Comment: I know computer geeks have problems with why questions and only ever get taught about material implication - I am one myself.  But they are really different things.

Answer (score 5):

The question is *'why does perl think -1 is true?'*.

The answer is when perl was developed it was decided that certain values would evaluate to false. These are:

- 0
- undef
- '' (empty string)

That is all I can think of a a suitable answer as to **why**. It was just designed that way.

Answer (score 3):

Only a 0 integer is considered false. Any other non-zero integer is considered true.

Comment: Not true. `""` returns something that is neither zero nor true.

Answer (score 2):

any integer <> 0 is true.
0 is always false.

Comment: Zero but true:  perl -E 'say "0e0" ? "True" : "False"'  A distinction has to be made in a language that doesn't have a strict typing system between strings and numbers.  0e0 can be a number, it can be a string (which even evaluates to zero), and it can be a true string (because of the e).  One minor point of occasional confusion.

Comment: @DavidO, True, but `"0e0"` doesn't return an integer in the CS sense.

Answer (score 2):

Perl took this behavior from `awk` and `C`.

Why `C` does it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329950/rationale-behind-return-0-as-default-value-in-c-c).